# How to: Find a control ID in insert/edit mode of a Telerik RadGrid

Tags: datepicker, telerik, jquery-ui-datepicker, radgrid

I have an application that have been developed before I started working and the datepickers are custom. we recently migrated to Windows 8 and the custom datepickers are not working anymore. So I started to change them for jquery-ui datepicker and everything was going like I was expecting. But now I face a problem. some of those custom datepickers are in the edit/insert mode of the Telerik RadGrid. My jquery-ui datepicker pop-up when the text-box receive focus with some java-script using the control's id. I have no problem making the new control appear in edit/insert mode with the right value in it. My problem is that I cannot find the control's id of the edit/insert mode of the RadGrid to pop-up the datepicker when the control receive focus. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet.

**ASPX**

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <telerik:RadStyleSheetManager ID="RadStyleSheetManager1" runat="server" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </telerik:RadScriptManager>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function TextBoxFocus(obj) {
                alert(obj.id);
                //Access client ID here
            }
            function RadTextBoxFocus(sender, args) {
                alert(sender.get_id());
                //Access client ID here
            }
        </script>
        <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
        </telerik:RadAjaxManager>
        <div>
            <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource" OnItemDataBound="RadGrid1_ItemDataBound">
                <MasterTableView>
                    <Columns>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" UniqueName="ID"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="Name" DataField="Name">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <telerik:RadTextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'>
                                    <ClientEvents OnFocus="RadTextBoxFocus" />
                                </telerik:RadTextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                        <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn></telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
                    </Columns>
                </MasterTableView>
            </telerik:RadGrid>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**ASPX.CS**

```
protected void RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
    dt.Rows.Add(1, "Name1");
    dt.Rows.Add(2, "Name2");
    dt.Rows.Add(3, "Name3");
    RadGrid1.DataSource = dt;
}

protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is GridEditableItem && e.Item.IsInEditMode)
    {
        GridEditableItem item = e.Item as GridEditableItem;
        TextBox TextBox1 = item["ID"].Controls[0] as TextBox;
        TextBox1.Attributes.Add("onfocus", "TextBoxFocus(this);");
    }
}
```

Let me know if any concern.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to access the control , I don't know if I did something very bad since it is pretty simple.

ASPX

```
<asp:TextBox ID="BoxILookFor" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("myValue") %>' />
```

ASPX.CS

```
protected void myGrid_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Item is GridEditableItem) && (e.Item.IsInEditMode))
    {
        GridEditableItem myItem = (GridEditableItem)e.Item;       
        TextBox myBox = (TextBox)myItem.FindControl("BoxILookFor");
        string myID = myBox.ClientID.ToString();
        myGrid.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<script type='text/javascript'>$('#" + myID + "').datepicker();</script>"));
    }
}
```

But now I face another problem, my textbox (datepicker) saves an empty string no mather what value (what date) I choose.